# how to read cross-section dataset as contingency table in r

Tags: r, statistics, correspondence

Since the most of tutorial only teaches way to make 2-ways table by using the particular categorical variable;

However, what if I want to analyze all of my variable as categorical? for example, this is my original dataset:

```
Countries population GDP   Schooling 

the US    123123123  123  22

china     34562351234 345  33

japan     8937927312  345345  44

England    23482374   345345  44
```

in this case, how can I make the 3x3 datasets as contingency table for example, I want country's name as my row, and other variables as column, in need of Correspondence Analysis?

Comment: Making reference to some "tutorial" and then not showing any specific result as desired that is different than what appears in the "data". Very unclear.

Comment: Are you trying to do a 3x3 Fisher's Test?